# Как изменять элемент массива на 1

Tags: javascript, массивы

Код:

```
var win = [];

function save() {  
        win[0] = win[0] + 1;
    }
```

Нужно, чтобы первый элемент в массиве менялся на 1 каждый раз, когда выполняется функция `save`. При этом, если запросить первый элемент массива в любой момент, даже после перезагрузки страницы - он выдаст измененное число.

Comment: Попробуй переформулировать вопрос и более подробно описать...
При каких обстоятельствах (событиях), должна запускаться функция...  Ну а на данный момент, советую почитать о `localstorage  cookie && БД`,  если есть желание получить какие либо измененные данные после перезагрузки страницы...

Comment: про localstorage знаю, а вот про массивы не очень, подумал что можно изменять значение ячеек без необходимости использовать LS или БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var win = [0];
if (localStorage.getItem("savedWin"))
  win = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedWin"));

function save() {  
  win[0] = win[0] + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("savedWin", JSON.stringify(win));
}
```

Comment: Всё-таки без LS не обошлось) тогда можете сказать, сколько он сможет хранить числовых массивов? И сохраненные данные могут удалится только если очистить LS, или если очистить куки тоже?

Comment: @user278370 Могу сказать - сколько угодно, постольку поскольку общий размер данных не превышает 5 MB.